# Using VS2003 and VS2010 Crystal Reports versions (9.1 and 13) on the same server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

We have a long-running environment with Crystal 9.1 from VS2003 (or was it VS.Net - can't remember any more). We've added new framework versions and used new versions of VS as time goes on, but we've never upgraded the Crystal version. With the simplicity of installing the Crystal 13 that comes with VS2010, however, I persuaded my boss to take a chance on upgrading our apps as we roll out fixes/updates to them. I converted an app from VS2005 and its reports to Crystal 13, installed framework 4.0 and Crystal 13 on our dev server, and all looked good. Then installed same on UAT, and all still looked good. Before I rolled it out to production, however, I had to make some changes to another very large app in a short enough timeframe that I could not upgrade it to VS2010/Crystal 13. Now I can't run the 9.1 Crystal reports on the large app in dev, and I'm afraid to move it to UAT if I can't even run them in dev. The most annoying part is that I'm not even getting an error message - it just doesn't work. I don't *know* that the addition of Crystal 13 caused the issue, but I made no changes to the report generation in this release and have no other explanation.

The details:
VS 2008 app with a 9.1 Crystal Report created in the application and exported to a pdf file on local server. I get no errors, but no pdf file ever gets exported or saved. I have confirmed that the user id running the application pool has access to the folder where it should be saved. I have confirmed that creating the report in preview mode in VS2008 and then exporting it from the preview window to that same folder does work. I found several references to running 10.5 with 13, but nothing about 9.1 with 13, and what they mentioned for 10.5 does not seem to apply to 9.1. The servers are running Windows Server 2003 SP2.

Has anyone successfully used Crystal 9.1 and Crystal 13 on the same server? I'm running out of time, year-end freeze is almost upon us, so I have to get these fixes out before (including running them through QA and UAT) early November or they get delayed to late January and that will NOT make my boss happy.

Any and all help greatly appreciated! Thanks, Bonnie